# import woes when reorganizing modules

Tags: python, import

I'm learning python (slowly) and I'm having an import problem.  All of my modules are in the same directory.  I have a module(commandler.py) with a class'Command' and a subclass of 'Command'. It works fine, but I know I'll have a lot more subclasses of command so I'm trying to reorganize and really struggling.

I'm trying to add a new module(shVRFCmd.py) with just a subclass of Command. I want shVRFCmd.py and commandler.py to move to a subdirectory 'commands'.  I feel like I've exhausted all the location/import possibilities and for my trouble I get the decidedly vague error:
'module' object has no attribute test_commandler when I run my unit tests.

Here are the actual files.  I'd love any pointers I can get.
https://github.com/natemarks/CiscoXMLPexpect/tree/master/CiscoXMLPexpect

Comment: Have you tried running: `commandler.test_commandler()`? (after you do the import of course)

Comment: That's the funny thing  there is nothing called test_commandler.  It seems to be something unittest assumes should exist based on something I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out, but it's a little embarrassing. My troubleshooting process included  adding and changing a number of imports. Unfortunately, one of those included adding an impossible import of the subclass in the module that contained my superclass.  Sadly, it's too much to expect python error messaging to save me from myself.

Note to self:  next time 50% more patient and 50% less stupid